# How to train one model for several devices

Tags: machine-learning, model, time-series, prediction

I have some tabular device data comprising a

```
time column, some tabular features, target classes
```

There are around 500 rows (not same) in all devices data and target classes are same.

I have same data for  around 1000 devices, 
I want to train a general model for all the devices for detecting the class.

Can someone help me with the approach to train for the target variable. What kind of models work in this condition

Answer (score 0):

If your device type is part of the data, you can train a decision tree. If the device type feature is important for classification sake, it will be added to the tree. First, create the device type features yourself - a binary column for each device type, like done in one-hot encoding. There will be a binary column per device type - is_device_samsung, is_device_lg, is_device_iphone and so forth. The number of columns created is equal to the number of device types. All but one of these columns will be 0, and the one indicating the current type will be 1. This will not guarantee the device type will be a part of the model - but let the AI decide this for you.
BTW - don't use get_dummies unless you know how to reuse it exactly as needed in the test data.

Another option is to use the python-weka wrapper, which accepts nominal attributes:

Example:

```
import weka.core.jvm as jvm
from weka.core.converters import Loader
from weka.classifiers import Classifier

def get_weka_prob(inst):
    dist = c.distribution_for_instance(inst)
    p = dist[next((i for i, x in enumerate(inst.class_attribute.values) if x == 'DONE'), -1)]
    return p

jvm.start()

loader = Loader(classname="weka.core.converters.CSVLoader")
data = loader.load_file(r'.\recs_csv\df.csv')
data.class_is_last()

datatst = loader.load_file(r'.\recs_csv\dftst.csv')
datatst.class_is_last()

c = Classifier("weka.classifiers.trees.J48", options=["-C", "0.1"])

c.build_classifier(data)
print(c)
probstst = [get_weka_prob(inst) for inst in datatst]

jvm.stop()
```

Weka models are different models that use a java bridge to python - the methods are java methods that can be called using this bridge. To use the dataframe in sklearn - you would have to manipulate it with one-hot encoding. Note that the nominal attributes in weka cannot have any special character in them. so use

```
df = df.replace([',', '"', "'", "%", ";"], '', regex=True)
```

for any nominal attribute before saving it to csv.
If you want to ensure that the model_type feature will be included in your model, you can trick it and add a dummy model type - and ensure that the class column for this dummy model is always "1" or "True" - depending on your class variable. If you have enough rows with this dummy model - j48 will open it as the first branch. Once the attribute is selected by j48 - it will be branched for all of the model types, not just the dummy one.

Comment: for 1000 (or more) devices this is not feasible. Neither computationally nor for good modelling

Comment: Another option is to use python-weka wrapper. See my update above